# how to realize owncloud-like history preserving with git-annex

Tags: git, git-annex

Owncloud allows to [preserve only certain parts of the file history](http://doc.owncloud.org/server/6.0/user_manual/files/versioncontrol.html) in order to optimize space consumption, e.g. for the last week keep two versions a day, for the last month one version a week, and so on.

How do I realize a similar behavior with git-annex, e.g. a cronjob that runs each night and drops all undesired file contents of previous file versions from all (special-) remotes, so that they don't consume any disk space at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this subject the git-annex website seems to be in error at present.  I note that, according to the website, you should be able to call

```bash
git annex sync --content --all
```

to have git-annex consider all files, including unused files, as it computes the files to transfer according to your [preferred content rules](http://git-annex.branchable.com/preferred_content/), but for me git-annex complains that `--all` is not an option for sync.

If that did work, you could then build a preferred content rule, perhaps even using time data.  I'm not certain about that aspect